# Jump to a `cl-defstruct` defined function like `find-function`

Tags: help-mode

A `cl-defstruct` may create several functions.  I would like to jump to the initial definition where everything is defined, similar to `find-function`.  How can I do that?

Comment: You're probably better off asking @Stefan directly :P.

Comment: My understanding is that these functions aren't defined in files, so, jumping to them is not possible. They exist as compiled objects in interpreter's memory. What you could do, is to call `disassemble` to see what the function will do.

Answer (score 1):

This is not 100% what you want, but may still be of some interest. I don't think you can "jump" to the definition of a function defined in `cl-defstruct` macro, but you can still get some idea of what it does, for example, like this:

Suppose, you defined this struct:

```
(cl-defstruct foo bar)
```

Then, you would get, for example, also defined function `foo-bar`, you can look up its bytecode like this:

```
(disassemble #'foo-bar)
;; byte code for foo-bar:
;;   args: (cl-x)
;; 0       constant  vectorp
;; 1       varref    cl-x
;; 2       call      1
;; 3       goto-if-nil 1
;; 6       varref    cl-x
;; 7       length    
;; 8       constant  2
;; 9       geq       
;; 10      goto-if-nil 1
;; 13      varref    cl-x
;; 14      constant  0
;; 15      aref      
;; 16      varref    cl-struct-foo-tags
;; 17      memq      
;; 18      goto-if-not-nil 2
;; 21:1    constant  signal
;; 22      constant  wrong-type-argument
;; 23      constant  foo
;; 24      varref    cl-x
;; 25      list2     
;; 26      call      2
;; 27      discard   
;; 28:2    varref    cl-x
;; 29      constant  1
;; 30      aref      
;; 31      return
```

This is roughly what this bytecode amounts to:

```
(defun foo-bar (cl-x)
  (if (and (vectorp cl-x)
           (>= (length cl-x) 2))
      (if (memq (aref cl-x 0) cl-struct-foo-tags)
          (progn
            (aref cl-x 1)
            (return)))
    (signal wrong-type-argument (list foo cl-x))))
```

Comment: Thank you -- I will add this to my arsenal of goodies.  I had previously been relying only upon `symbol-function` to inspect whatever value is available from said function, but it is not as detailed as `disassemble`.